# maven ant echoproperties task

Tags: maven

I am new to maven. I have written build scripts using ant. I am trying to display all the evn properties, user defined properties, system properties etc. in maven. In ant i could do the following .

I tried to do the same with maven with the maven-antrun-plugin

But get the following error.

```
Embedded error: Could not create task or type of type: echoproperties.
Ant could not find the task or a class this task relies upon.
```

How can i see all properties in maven with or without using echoproperties. This is my configuration in maven

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.plugin.antrun.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>Displaying value of properties</echo>
                            <echo>[org.junit.version] ${org.junit.version}</echo>
                            <echoproperties prefix="org" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine for me with `maven` 2.2.1 and 3.0.1.  Snippet of the run...

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Sun Dec 26 20:08:02 IST 2010
[echoproperties] org.aspectj\:aspectjrt\:jar=D\:\\maven\\.m2\\repository\\org\\a
spectj\\aspectjrt\\1.6.8\\aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
[echoproperties] org.aspectj\:aspectjweaver\:jar=D\:\\maven\\.m2\\repository\\or
g\\aspectj\\aspectjweaver\\1.6.8\\aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar
...
```

Which version of `maven` are you using (latest is 3.0.1)?  Which version of `maven-antrun-plugin` (latest is 1.6)?

The latest version of `maven-antrun-plugin` gives a deprecated warning for `<tasks>` tag.  `<target>` should be used instead.

```
<configuration>
    <target>
         <echoproperties prefix="org" />
     </target>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works when i do mvn install but does not work when i do mvn validate. Any reason why

Comment: Probably because the default phase is install, but not validate. Add a phase definition element <phase>validate</phase> to the execution element