# Maven pom systemProperty path to file syntax

Tags: file, syntax, path, maven, properties

Have follwong chunk from `pom.xml`:

```
<systemProperty>
    <name>axis2.config</name>
    <value>file:${project.build.directory}/../../axis2.properties</value>
</systemProperty>
```

what does syntax for `value` tag mean?

`/../` - is id `cd ..` and forwards to parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short: `../` means parent direcory

long version:

- `file:` specifies, that the following
  content should be interpreted as a
  file path.
- `${project.build.directory}` is a
  variable which will be replaced by
  the runtime with the actual project
  build directory
- `/` are folder separators
- `..` means parent folder
- `axis2.properties` is the name of the
  properties file

if you want to display the path for debugging purposes you might want to have a look at this:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-display-the-value-of-a-pom-xml-element.html

or

[maven ant echoproperties task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532687/maven-ant-echoproperties-task)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a relative path to the project build directory, and go upper (in parent) two times.

In other words: it's the parent directory of the directory that contain your project build directory ;)

**Source:** [Maven Properties Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

Comment: oh, thanks to you Alois.is it possible to see how the whole path looks like? i mean to display this variable value,perhaps somewhere in out.println?

Comment: I don't think so, but if your project build directory is in let's say: /home/sergio/projects/myproject/target --> /home/sergio/projects/axis2.properties

Comment: You can find more informations here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide  hope that's help !