# How do I write a file with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Basically, I am looking for the maven equivalent of Ant's `<echo>` task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [maven ant echoproperties task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532687/maven-ant-echoproperties-task)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maven plugins can be used for this. Under the hood a maven plugin basically uses jelly to execute ant tasks.  Anything done in ant can be done in maven.  Check out this plugin for running ant tasks: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html

Comment: You can use antrun-plugin to do anything you could otherwise do in Ant, but the statement that all maven plugins "basically uses jelly to execute ant tasks" is false - unless you only mean to refer to this one plugin and not all.

Comment: nothing about this is right. maven-antrun uses no jelly, and no other maven plugin I've helped maintain does, either.