# export all defined maven project properties to file?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven 3 project. In the POM, I define numerous `<properties>` - some under `<project>`, others under specific `<profile>`. is the a way in maven to export all declared properties to a .properties file?

My current way of doing so is to:

1. create env.properties file in src/main/resources
2. for each property 'myProp' add this line to env.properties: `myProp=${myProp}`
3. enable resource filtering during builds

Seems like there ought to be a way to eliminate step 2 above...

thanks,
-nikita

Comment: You need to export the properties to the file for every build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) and its write-project-properties goal.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you can do this using the [antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) coupled with Ant's [echoproperties task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html). An example of this configuration is in the [StOf question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532687/maven-ant-echoproperties-task).

Comment: Thanks, Spencer. Useful, but not ideal: echoproperties will either list all properties (including maven. and other sys properties). Limiting by prefix doesn't work for me because our project's properties dont have a common prefix. I'd need to scope properties to "those declared in this POM"